# HTML Javascript - Need help learning to transition to 3D from Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d

So now I can pretty much do almost whatever I want in 2 dimensional games/apps, using HTML Javascript Canvas.

Problem is now I want to make some 3D applications, but have NO IDEA where to start.

3D is completely new to me and I think regardless it seems like it will be very difficult for me to learn, but I want to try - I just don't know what to do now.

I've looked into three.js a bit, but it's chinese for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I am very new to tech. The way I am learning html, css and soon javascript and j query is ...
1. first find a good you tube tutorials and just watch it irrespective of whether I understand it completely or not.
2. I watch those videos second time but try to take notes as much as possible. And because of the links and the comments in youtube, I usually land up with good study material (book).
3. I study the same language in different way- book or other videos.
I just thought of sharing with you. I hope it helps.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

start learning from three.js
  [three.js](http://threejs.org)

you can create mini to almost-enterprise quality of application with it. But here is a little issue, if you think about creating large games, where you need to put a lot of collisions , you can try  [babylon.js](https://www.babylonjs.com/)

they are for your coding aspect. Besides, you need to learn blender/3d studio max. try to get the basic philosophy of three basic operations (i suppose you already have..) rotation,translation,scaling.

try to edit the examples of three.js and see what it comes, trust me, it is not that tough that you are thinking.

After that, you can try shader (GLSL). you can find many shader examples in [GLSL playground](http://glslsandbox.com/e) and [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/)

Also [this](http://learningthreejs.com/) website is legendary for learning three.js

and try some others libraries like playcanvas,unity3d(webGL)

happy learning